# How to launch instruments from the command line with xcode 5.1 and have the simulator be iOS6

Tags: xcode5, ios-simulator, instruments

Using Xcode 5.1
Have existing scripts which launch the simulator from the command line to run scripts for automation testing of our app.
This works fine for iOS 7.1

From in the instruments UI, I can specify launching the simulator against iOS 6.1
Is there a command line switch to do the same?  Something like:
instruments -t "${AUTOMATION_TEMPLATE}" "${LAUNCH_TARGET}" -e UIASCRIPT "${SCRIPT}" **-e SDK_VERSION iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk** -v -l 20

Right now, I have installs of xcode 4.6 and xcode 4.4.1 that I can switch between to run against iOS6 and iOS5 respectively, and this seems to work fine.  (I just rename the xcode.app file and get the results I want.)  But I have been told that the earlier versions of Xcode won't launch on Mavericks, so my test development machine is held back from upgrading and co-workers who have upgraded cannot run these tests, making me a chokepoint.

I have seen references from 6 months ago that seem to say there is no command line switch for this, but that's a couple renditions back on Xcode 5, so maybe…?

Answer (score -1):

I have Xcode 5.1 running on Mavericks and I can trigger the iOS 6.1 simulator from the command line. Just pass the **-sdk iphonesimulator6.1** parameter and it should work.